# code to generate radio button in existing wp theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, radio-button

Good evening friends and neighbors,

I am currently utilizing MAMP v6.6 to customize and build wordpress themes locally on my
2017 iMac (Retina ~ 27 inch) running macOS Monterey 12.2

Also using:

- Apache Netbeans 12.6
- MySQL Workbench 8.0
- Xdebug (once I figure out how to install)

( can’t quite figure out how to install PECL - the line commands i found on the web are not doing it - in order to install Xdebug, but am working on that )

I’ve added a third ‘menu layout’ option to an existing premium wordpress theme (VEGA by themepunch)…. menu center,  with the menu centered underneath the logo by adding some PHP code to the ‘template-menu.php’, ‘functions.php’ and ‘menu.lib.php’ files.

However, this is not generating a radio button for that option in the ‘theme settings’ panel (located in the lefthand column Wordpress dashboard menu) under the ‘Header’ tab (see reference jpeg )

Please see reference images attached for more info.
[image: Theme Settings/Header tab/MENU SETTINGS/Menu layouts]

Here is the html source code in the 'theme settings' accessed via the wordpress dashboard left side menu:

```
<!---  html source code for ‘menu layouts’ in menu settings under header tab --->

<div class="rm_input rm_select">
    
    <label for="pp_menu_layout">Menu layouts</label>
        <br/>

    <div style="margin-top:5px;float:left;width:300px">
        
        <div style="float:left;margin:0 20px 20px 0">
            
        <input style="float:left;" id="pp_menu_layout" name="pp_menu_layout" type="radio"
        checked="checked"           value="1"/>
            
            <div style="float:left;width:90%;"><img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vega/functions/images/menu1.png"/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div style="float:left;margin:0 20px 20px 0">
            
        <input style="float:left;" id="pp_menu_layout" name="pp_menu_layout" type="radio"
                    value="2"/>
            
            <div style="float:left;width:90%;">
            
                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vega/functions/images/menu2.png"/>
            
            </div>
        
        </div>
    
    <small></small>
    
    <div class="clearfix">
        
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
</div>
```

[image: current front page displaying two menu layouts]
It’s probably something fairly easy, however, if anyone can give some guidance or speculation on what code to add in what file in order to generate the radio button for my third ‘menu layout option’, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends and neighbors,

I was able to figure this answer out by meticulously going through each file within the VEGA premium wordpress theme. When I opened the admin.lib.php file, I realized that it correlated directly with the 'Theme Settings' menu panel.
So I scrolled down til I got to the MENU SETTINGS-->Menu Layouts section of PHP code. There I just copied the value '2' menu option in the array and pasted that underneath on the next line. Then added a number 3 in place of the number 2 in the pasted code.

```
    "desc" => "",
    "id" => SHORTNAME."_menu_layout",
    "type" => "radio",
    "options" => array(
        '1' => '<div style="float:left;width:90%;"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/functions/images/menu1.png"/></div>',
        '2' => '<div style="float:left;width:90%;"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/functions/images/menu2.png"/></div>',
        '3' => '<div style="float:left;width:90%;"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/functions/images/menu3.png"/></div>',
    ),
```

I had already created a thumbnail jpeg for menu layout number three (menu3.png) and placed it into the /functions/images directory.

This generated a new radio button and thumbnail image for my custom menu layout in the 'Theme Settings'-->'Header Tab' menu.

[image: VEGA theme menu layout options revised]